# Помогите подобрать алгоритм

Tags: алгоритм

Какой алгоритм использовать?

**Задача:**

> В Берляндском государственном университете локальная сеть между
>   серверами не всегда работает без ошибок. При передаче двух одинаковых
>   сообщений подряд возможна ошибка, в результате которой эти два
>   сообщения сливаются в одно. При таком слиянии конец первого сообщения
>   совмещается с началом второго. Конечно, совмещение может происходить
>   только по одинаковым символам. Длина совмещения должна быть
>   положительным числом, меньшим длины текста сообщения.
>
> Например, при передаче двух сообщений «abrakadabra» подряд возможно,
>   что оно будет передано с ошибкой описанного вида, и тогда будет
>   получено сообщение вида «abrakadabrabrakadabra» или
>   «abrakadabrakadabra» (в первом случае совмещение произошло по одному
>   символу, а во втором — по четырем).
>
> По полученному сообщению t определите, возможно ли, что это результат
>   ошибки описанного вида работы локальной сети, и если возможно,
>   определите возможное значение s.
>
> Не следует считать ошибкой ситуацию полного наложения друга на друга
>   двух сообщений. К примеру, если получено сообщение «abcd», следует
>   считать, что в нём ошибки нет. Аналогично, простое дописывание одного
>   сообщения вслед за другим не является признаком ошибки. Например, если
>   получено сообщение «abcabc», следует считать, что в нём ошибки нет.
>
> Входные данные В единственной строке выходных данных следует непустая
>   строка t, состоящая из строчных букв латинского алфавита. Длина строки
>   t не превосходит 100 символов.
>
> Выходные данные Если сообщение t не может содержать ошибки, выведите
>   «NO» (без кавычек) в единственную строку выходных данных.
>
> В противном случае в первой строке выведите «YES» (без кавычек), а в
>   следующей строке выведите строку s — возможное сообщение, которое
>   могло привести к ошибке. Если возможных ответов несколько, разрешается
>   вывести любой из них.

**Примеры:**

---

входные данные

```
abrakadabrabrakadabra
```

выходные данные

```
YES
abrakadabra
```

---

входные данные

```
acacacaca
```

выходные данные

```
YES
acaca
```

---

входные данные

```
abcabc
```

выходные данные

```
NO
```

---

входные данные

```
abababab
```

выходные данные

```
YES
ababab
```

---

входные данные

```
tatbt
```

выходные данные

```
NO
```

---

*Примечание:*

*Во втором примере подходящим ответом также является строка acacaca.*

Comment: в примерах **abcabc** и **tatbt** у вас не указанны выходные данные просто **NO**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Находим длину строки t и целочисленным делением её середину (если длина нечетна - начинаем со среднего символа, если четна - с того, который слева от средины).
2. Проходим по строке в обратном направлении от этого среднего символа до второго включительно (но не до первого - иначе это просто совпадение строк).
3. Рассматриваем подстроку от текущего символа до конца.
4. Если подстрока совпадает с началом основной строки - вывод `YES` и подстроки и завершение работы, если нет - идем к следующему символу. Если дошли до конца безуспешно - выводим `NO`.

На С++ выглядит примерно так:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void test(const string t)
{
    for(size_t l = (t.length()-1)/2, i = l; i > 0; --i)
    {
        string s = t.substr(i);
        if (t.find(s) == 0)
        {
            cout << "YES\n" << s << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << "NO\n";
}


int main()
{
    vector<string> s =
    {
        "abrakadabrabrakadabra",
        "acacacaca",
        "abcabc",
        "abababab",
        "tatbt"
    };
    for(auto t: s)
    {
        cout << "---- " << t << endl;;
        test(t);
    }
}
```